# Generate cyclic column variable conditional on lag of another variable postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

So suppose I have a table as follows:

```
    user  date
    a     10/15/2015
    a     11/15/2015
    a     12/15/2015
    a      2/15/2015
    b      1/15/2015
    b      2/15/2015
    b      4/15/2015
    b      6/15/2015
```

I need to create three column variables (acutally two - i figured the time lag variable) (1) one that counts the number of successive logins by month and if there is a lapse restarts the counter (2) the numbers of days between logins (figured this one out) (3) if the counter resets then their cycle count increases by one. The resulting table should look as follows: (I am going to just use 30 days for 1 month span for illustrative purposes.)

```
    user  date         count     timelapse   cycle
    a     10/15/2015    1          0           1
    a     11/15/2015    2          30          1
    a     12/15/2015    3          30          1
    a      2/15/2015    1          60          2
    b      1/15/2015    1          0           1
    b      2/15/2015    2          30          1 
    b      4/15/2015    1          60          2
    b      6/15/2015    1          60          3
```

Any ideas? I was able to get the count column to work - but I could not get it to reset when the timelapse was greater than 30. Since the cycle was conditional on two columns I was at a bit of a loss there.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should show the query that handles the 5th column.  And, can you have more than one record in a month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the idea.  Use `lag()` to determine when a gap occurs.  You can do this by truncating the date to the beginning of the month, for comparison purposes.

Then, do a cumulative sum of the gap flags.  This provides the `cycle` column.  The count is then `row_number()` using the `cycle`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by user, cycle order by date) as count
from (select t.*, sum(IsGap) over (partition by user order by date) as cycle
      from (select user, date,
                   (case when date_trunc('month', date) = date_trunc('month', lag(date) over (partition by user order by date) + interval '1 month'
                         then 0
                         else 1
                    end) as IsGap
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
```